# Adding data entered in a textbox in VB.NET2010 to my ms-access database field

Tags: database-connection, ms-access-2010, vb.net-2010

I am having problems in VB.NET with adding data from a textbox to my database. For example i have a texbox where I want the student to enter there name, when they press the button okay I want the data in that textbox to be saved in a new row in the field "Name" under the entity "Student".

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly you'll have to be connected to the Db, which I assume you are. Then the way to do it would be to say something like :

```
    Dim student as string = txt.text
    Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand("Insert INTO Student ([First Name]) VALUES "(student)"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

That *should* work, otherwise you have to add parameters manually